# Inverse this Stokes Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

**I am looking for a way to compute the inverse** of the $d \times d$ matrix by defined  $M_\xi:= \xi \otimes \xi - |\xi|^2 I_d,$

where $(\xi \otimes \xi)_{ij}= \xi_i \, \xi_j.$

To give a litle bit of physical background, I believe this matrix should be invertible as it is the pseudo-differential operator of the Stokes operator $- P_\sigma \Delta$ where $P_\sigma$ is the Leray projector.

I'm also expecting $M_\xi^{-1}$ to depend morally on $|\xi|^{-2}$ as we should "integrate twice" in the Fourier space.

Any help is welcomed.

**Edit 1** Thanks for your help @BenGrossmann and @CalvinKhor. Indeed it seems like my matrix is not invertible since $Ker(M_{\xi})=span(\xi) \neq \{0 \}$ . I was thinking of restricting the beginning space of the linear function $f_\xi$ linked to $M_\xi$. If I assume that $u \in \{v \in \mathbb{R}^d, \ \text{such that }v \cdot \xi = 0 \} = Span(\xi)^\perp$, I think I can inverse the equality
$$M_{\xi} u = w$$
for any $w \in Span(\xi)^\perp$. Moreover this restriction to $ Span(\xi)^\perp$ makes sense as it corresponds to the divergence-free condition of the Stokes equation. I need to study the linear function $\tilde{f}_{\xi} : Span(\xi)^\perp \rightarrow Span(\xi)^\perp $ and try to find a good invertible expression of its corresponding matrix ($d-1 \times d-1$).

**Edit 2** Actually, one can show that for any $u \in Span(\xi)^\perp$, one has $M_\xi u = -|\xi|^2 u$, so the matrix of $\tilde{f}_{\xi} $ is the same in every base of $Span(\xi)^\perp$ and is given by $- |\xi|^2 I_{d-1}$. This matrix is invertible and its inverse is given by $-|\xi|^{-2} I_{d-1}$.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding something-If $\xi=(1,0)$, isn't $M_\xi=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ ie not invertible?

Comment: You have basically rediscovered that the rank-1 matrix $\xi\otimes \xi/|\xi|^2$  is projection to the span of $\xi$ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, $M$ has no inverse. To see that this is the case, note that the vector $\xi$ satisfies
$$
M_{\xi}\xi = (\xi \otimes \xi - |\xi^2|I)\xi = 
(\xi \otimes \xi)\xi - |\xi^2|\xi = |\xi|^2\xi - |\xi|^2\xi = 0.
$$
Because $M$ has a non-trivial nullspace, it cannot be invertible.

Comment: @Velobos Actually, I just realized that the answer is incorrect. I had an incorrect sign in the denominator: the denominator actually simplifies to zero. Correspondingly, $M$ has no inverse.

Comment: @BenGrossmann right, OK thats what I was thinking. As $I_d-\xi\otimes\xi$ is afterall, orthogonal projection from the span of $\xi$ (I'm not OP)